# Erroneous Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, windows, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

So, I've retreived a line from a text file and stored it as one string in an array of strings and I've called it inventorylist[i]. I then split it using .split(" ") and store the tokens from that in array called invlistTokens. When I do anything with that token array, it throws an out of bounds exception. If I put it in a forloop to display the 5 tokens I expect, it will succeed in reading them and THEN throw that exception.

```
    public static item[] loadInv(){
    String inventoryname = "Henderson_j_inv.txt";
    String[] inventorylist= new String[50]; //more than enough room for the file to load in
    String[] invlistTokens = new String [5];
    item[] inventory = new item[50];

    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(inventoryname);
        inventorylist = file.OpenFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("FILE FAILED TO LOAD");
    }

    for(int i=0; i< Array.getLength(inventorylist); i++){
        System.out.println(inventorylist[i]);//This always succeeds
        invlistTokens=inventorylist[i].split(" ");

        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){  //This is the weird ForLoop. It completes and then java throws out of bounds.
            System.out.println(invlistTokens[j]);
        }
    }
```

Please excuse my messy post, this is my first post and I'm not sure how specific I can be about such a weird error

Eclipse Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYals.jpg

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

I did get the variable right in my actual code, just happened to be a dummy when adding the forloop to the post

This is the actual exception, except I know that it makes it past 1. The loop completes all 5 runs before it throws.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at shopping2.loadInv(shopping2.java:50)
    at shopping2.main(shopping2.java:23)
```

---

So I changed the code to this

```
public static item[] loadInv(){
    String inventoryname = "Henderson_j_inv.txt";
    String[] inventorylist= new String[50];
    String[] invlistTokens = new String [100];
    item[] inventory = new item[50];

    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(inventoryname);
        inventorylist = file.OpenFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("FILE FAILED TO LOAD");
    }

    System.out.print(inventorylist.length); //This displays 19, when it should be giving me 10 based on my file

    for(int i=0; i< inventorylist.length; i++){
        //System.out.println(inventorylist[i]);
        invlistTokens=inventorylist[i].split(" ");
        System.out.println(invlistTokens.length); //This alternates between 5 and 1


    }
```

So I think the problem is either in my txt file or my reader class. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: Can you add the stactrace and mark the line where the exception occurs?

Comment: In the last loop, do you really write `System.out.println("invlistTokens[i]");` or you do mean `System.out.println(invlistTokens[i]);`?

Comment: Is this the actual code? This inner for loop just prints a string.

Comment: What exactly is `ReadFile`? I am not finding that in the Java 7 API

Comment: @Daniel I think it's a custom class - the method he's using is not named according to standards either, look at the capital first letter.

Comment: That is the actual code, I had tried something different in eclipse  after this happened. I typo'd while I was adding the forloop back in the post.

Comment: Readfile is a custom class that loads a .txt into a string[] one line per string. That does work, I made sure of it.

Comment: @Meatuchu Incorrect looping variable, see my answer.

Comment: Meatuchu, Thanks. @Evan Knowles, with the edited code your answer makes sense.

Comment: Please paste the stacktrace - can't view imgur links.

Comment: @EvanKnowles I did get the variable correct in my running code. I removed the forloop while experimenting on it and before I posted it I typed it directly back into the post and made several mistakes doing so.

Comment: @Meatuchu Are you sure this `invlistTokens=inventorylist[i].split(" ");` gives you back an array with 5 elements? - Nevermind..saw your imgur now..looks like 5 elements there

Comment: @Daniel 100%. it does manage to print all 5 tokens before throwing the exception.

Comment: Remove the inner loop, print the output of `invlistTokens.length` in each iteration of the outer loop and let's see some output (assuming it's not pages-long) :) Please paste it in the question so that Evan can also take a look at it

Comment: It seems that on the second iteration of `i`, `inventorylist[i]` is an empty list. So, `.split(" ")` return a one-element array with an empty string at index 0. That's why on the second iteration of `j` you got ArrayIndexoutOfBounds at index 1.

Comment: Good catch, @Benjamin. It could be why he has two new lines until the exception is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see two `\n` before the stack trace, `System.out.println()` seems to be called twice with an empty String.

So it seems that on the second iteration of `i`, `inventorylist[i]` is an empty String. So `.split(" ")` returns a single-element array with an empty String at index `0`.

That's why on the second iteration of `j`, you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at index `1`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your text source contains two lines!**

The first line is the one from your screenshot:

> 01 MusicCD 100 20 5.00

The second one is a simple empty line.

So your little program loops correctly over the first line, printing out the correct results. Then it loops over the second (empty) line and does the following:

1. Print out the empty line. Look at your screenshot. It contains this written empty line.
2. Split this empty string by space, resulting in a 1-element-array.
3. Looping over this 1-element-array, printing out correctly the first element (another empty line -> look at screenshot).
4. Correctly throwing an AIOOBE for index 1 because there is no such index.

Conclusion: Check for empty lines before going into the loop. Or check the number of elements in the split array.